# Importing old library which imports its modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2

In our company we have a library, that is divided into modules. These modules are in separate files and each of this modules have it's dependencies on other modules. Each module has a definition function, which registers it for other modules to use it later and also it can require other modules in its definition function. The require is similar to angular:

```
modules.require(['authentication', 'data', 'http'], module => console.log('Here is my module: ', module).
```

The library has a Synchronizer class, which based on this require in each module, handles importing and providing of the required modules. When a module has not yet been required, it creates a `<script>` tag, set it's src to the required module file and appends it to the body.

Here is the problem, because if I just import the main file of my library and try to require some module, it appends a `<script>` tag but the path to the file is not correct, because it is all bundled together by webpack.

Is there a way in webpack, to state, that this folder (folder with the plugin) should remain as is, so that I can then make requests to the individual files in this folder?

I have tried using "import" statement, "require" and also I tried to change the library into npm package, but I am not really allowed to change the library, because it has been tested in this format. So keeping the library as is, would be the best.

For example if I put this library into:

`./static/js/mylibrary`
then our library can produce for `modules.require(['data'], onSuccess)` a `<script>` tag with src like:

`./static/js/mylibrary/data.js`

Can I setup webpack so that the file stays there? In development? In production?

I am using a project created by vue-cli

Comment: Well it seems, that just simply putting it to the "public" directory in webpack did the trick for both, development and production. Don't know why I didn't try this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment simply putting it to the "public" directory in webpack did the trick for both, development and production. Don't know why I didn't try this before.